# Error in method parameters while implementing a generic Interface

Tags: java, generics, functional-interface

While implementing a basic generic interface in Java, I am unable to override the implemented method using the parameterized type I provide for the interface

I created an anonymous class to implement a generic functional interface I created, but when I tried overriding the method with the same parameterized type the compiler says that my implementation is not correct and that the method parameter should be an Object instead of a String (the parameterized type I provided to the generic interface)

Here is my interface

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface MyFuncInterface<T> {


    public void acceptAndPrint(T t);

}
```

and here is the snippet where I am trying to implement this via an anonymous class

```
MyFuncInterface<String> myFunc2 = new MyFuncInterface(){
            @Override
            public void acceptAndPrint(String s){
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }
```

When approaching this way I get the compiler error

> The type new MyFuncInterface(){} must implement the inherited abstract method MyFuncInterface.acceptAndPrint(Object)

I am pretty sure I am missing a generics concept here but I can't figure out that when I provided the parameterized argument `<T>` the type as `String`, why is it expecting my method to still take the argument as an `Object` type and not a `String` ? Is the answer related to tweaking something related to a generic method ?

Comment: I think you're using a raw type.  Try `new MyFuncInterface<>()`

Comment: Or `new MyFuncInterface<String>()`. Or better yet, `MyFuncInterface<String> myFunc2 = System.out::println;`.

Comment: Java 8 does not accept diamond operator with anonymous inner classes; apperently you need Java 9 or higher for that.  It does work with just a regular type parameter. `MyFuncInterface<String> myFunc2 = new MyFuncInterface<String>(){`

Comment: I cant believe I posted this question, @markspace - Correct, I was using a raw type , didn't realize I had only used the parameters during instantiation and not in the initialization. I will post this as solution to resolve , thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Realized my mistake, I hadn't provided parameterized type arguments during the initialization but only in the declaration.

```
MyFuncInterface<String> myFunc = new MyFuncInterface<String>() {

            @Override
            public void acceptAndPrint(String t) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a class object or a subclass object of that class as a parameter to the method.
Please go through the example of Bounded types with generics https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bounded-types-generics-java/